# 2 javascripts are conflicting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 javascripts that are conflicting with eachother, the newer one (Zeroclipboard) conflicts with the older one (delete row) and  won't let the **delete row** one work. The moment i removed the **zeroclipboard** one, **delete** worked.

Tried adding jQuery.noConflict(); but didn't seem to work. By reading few solutions, I decided to remove $ signs, but still no.

I have a **files.php** file, including the **header.php** file. I am adding the **custom.js** file in header.php, which holds many functions for operations across the project, including the delete row function. Whereas, the newer script for ZerClipboard is in **files.php** itself.

Older one, to delete a table row on delete icon click, which won't work after I add the next:

***custom.js***

```
function deleteRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;

    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
         current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))
            {
                var fid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('fid');
                var str=$(this).attr('rel');
                var data = 'fid=' + $(this).attr('rel') + '&uid=' + $(this).parent().attr('rel');   
                var deletethis = '#tr' + $(this).attr('rel');           
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
                $.ajax(
                {
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "delete.php",
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,

                       success: function(msg)
                       {
                            $(deletethis).fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                       }
                });             
        }
    });
    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
```

ZeroClipboard's JS and SWF, along with this js to copy some text on clipboard on Share icon click:

***files.php***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    var clip = null; 
    function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } 
   function init() 
   {
      clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
      clip.setHandCursor( true );
   } 
   function move_swf(ee)
   {    
      copything = document.getElementById(ee.id+"_text").value;
      clip.setText(copything); 
         if (clip.div)
         {    
            clip.receiveEvent('mouseout', null);
            clip.reposition(ee.id);         }
         else{ clip.glue(ee.id);   }  
         clip.receiveEvent('mouseover', null);  
   }    
</script>
```

I used this blog post for implementing multiple zerclipboard - http://blog.aajit.com/easy-multiple-copy-to-clipboard-by-zeroclipboard/
And, here's the HTML source generated by the files.php page - http://jpst.it/tlGU

Comment: Where is `deleteRow()` function used?
And where are `$` and `init` and `move_swf` used? Do they all need to be in the global object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the follow function definition of your second script:

`function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }`

Because this is redefining your `$` object in `window` context, due when you use `$` in your first script you're not using `jquery`, instead you're using your new function definition.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Lol, your comment up there helped and I had been forgetting to hit Ctrl+f5 :\
Umm, I do not know why the original author of that blog(code) had added that. Not knowing the basics of js, i was unsure if this line of code was unnecessary. I assumed the same and went ahead removing that line of code, but it still did not help me. Oh, wait, while trial and error I changed my custom.js multiple times. And some older one was cached and I guess all the solutions I tried might had worked. :|

Comment: I don't know why the example in the blog is defining this `function` because it isn't neither using it. anyway it's nice to help you `:)`

Comment: Hey, could you help me with adding a alert or notification after the share button is clicked on? I want to alert the user that text was copied to the clipboard once it has happened.

Comment: I've never been using this library, and I don't know what version are you using. However I take a look at: `http://zeroclipboard.org/` and I see that this is possible adding `aftercopy` event in your object with the follow code: `clip.on("aftercopy", function(event){  alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"]); });` I just tried with 2.1.6 version and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should use `noConflict()` :

```
function deleteRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;

    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
         current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }

jQuery.noConflict(); // Reinitiating $ to its previous state
jQuery(document).ready(function($) // "Protected" jQuery code : $ is referencing jQuery inside this function, but not necessarily outside
    {
        $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))
            {
                var fid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('fid');
                var str=$(this).attr('rel');
                var data = 'fid=' + $(this).attr('rel') + '&uid=' + $(this).parent().attr('rel');   
                var deletethis = '#tr' + $(this).attr('rel');           
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
                $.ajax(
                {
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "delete.php",
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,

                       success: function(msg)
                       {
                            $(deletethis).fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                       }
                });             
        }
    });
    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
```

And in files.php:

```
<script src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>

   var clip = null;

   function $(id) {
       return document.getElementById(id);
   }

   function init() {
       clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
       clip.setHandCursor(true);
   }

   function move_swf(ee) {
       copything = document.getElementById(ee.id + "_text").value;
       clip.setText(copything);
       if (clip.div) {
           clip.receiveEvent('mouseout', null);
           clip.reposition(ee.id);
       } else {
           clip.glue(ee.id);
       }
       clip.receiveEvent('mouseover', null);
   }
</script>
```